# Java Query and Enum

Tags: java, jpa, random, enums

I have a problem this getting result list from query. Query return me an  null Object. I dont have any idea why its happen. But if I comment its WHERE statement its work fine, but i have two Enum that can specify the result. I dosent think that Im first with it, and google didnt give any answer except to use NamedQuery. This is my code :

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public DeviceProfileAttribute getRandomDeviceProfileAttribute(Category category, Platform platform) {

    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM DeviceProfileAttribute d " +
            "WHERE d.tenantAttribute.attribute.category=:category AND " +
            "d.tenantAttribute.attribute.platform=:platform " +
            "ORDER BY RAND()");
    q.setParameter("category", category);
    q.setParameter("platform", platform);
    q.setMaxResults(1);
    if (q.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (DeviceProfileAttribute) q.getResultList().get(0);
    }

}
```

Im sure that null isnt only one answer.

Thanks in advance.

P.S May be somebody now to check this query after puting all parameters ?

P.P.S The problem is in using Enum and ORDER by RAND() in one SQL Query.

Comment: 'select d' is not valid SQL.  You can't select a table name from a table name.

Comment: but it not give any error, i think if its, it will give some sort of exception.

Comment: @Paul: `SELECT d` is valid JPQL.

Comment: How did you map the enumeration?

Comment: @Justin: As usually @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING).

Comment: Have you tried passing the string value as the parameter instead of the enum?  Doesn't sound right, but worth a try.

Comment: Are you saying that `q.getResultList() == null`, or that `q.getResultList().getEmpty() == true` and the method is returning null ?

Comment: @Justin: It wasn't my idea to make this Category and Platform as Enum, but my problem is how to solve it. Yes if I make Enum as String it work fine. Problem is this Enums =)

Comment: @Aaron: As you can see "if (q.getResultList().isEmpty()) { return null; }" give me null becose list is empty.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate?  If so, I would recommend printing the SQL to the log.  Let me know if you don't know how to do this.  My guess is that there is legitimately no data that matches.

Comment: Whichever JPA implementation you're using, basic debugging says print out the SQL that this JPQL maps to. That is the only way to understand why you get a particular result

Comment: @Justin: In DB is 50 or more values that can match with query. When I compile  my project i got IllegalArgumentException and its not runtime exception. May be somebody now to check this query after puting all parameters ?

Comment: @DataNucleus: How I can check the final SQL query?

Comment: Did you activate trace so that you can see the SQL statement to be executed?

Comment: @Nutsccracker.ua Look in the docs for whichever JPA implementation you're using. You haven't stated which it is ...

Comment: @nutscracker.ua Please state what DB Access layer you are using.  Is it Hibernate?  Also you mentioned an exception.  Could you add the stacktrace and print the line that it occurred on.

Comment: @Justin: yes its hibernate, that exception is solved, but main problem is still have its place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way out for me, is to use such code :

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)

public DeviceProfileAttribute getRandomDeviceProfileAttribute(Category category, Platform platform) {

Query q = em.createQuery(
        "SELECT d FROM DeviceProfileAttribute d " +
        "WHERE d.tenantAttribute.attribute.category=:category AND " +
        "d.tenantAttribute.attribute.platform=:platform "
);
q.setParameter("category", category);
q.setParameter("platform", platform);
if (q.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
    return null;
} else {
    return (DeviceProfileAttribute) q.getResultList().get( new Random().nextInt(q.getResultList().size()));;
}

}
```